# Best practice foreach new vs null

Tags: java, memory-management, arraylist

I have a method that iterate over a large array every 5 seconds. On each loop, I add something to an `ArrayList`.

I heard that using `new` takes more memory.

I need to know what's the best way to empty/clear above `ArrayList`.

```
private ArrayList<MyMarker> myArray;

public void callEveryFiveSeconds(){
    myArray = new ArrayList<MyMarker>(); //clears previous array data
    //grab array data from server
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
       myArray.add(someData);
    }
}
```

or

```
private ArrayList<MyMarker> myArray  = new ArrayList<MyMarker>();

public void callEveryFiveSeconds(){
    myArray = null; //clears previous array data
    //grab array data from server
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
       myArray.add(someData);
    }
}
```

Comment: The second one will result in a NullPointerException

Comment: Second one will give you an NPE.

Comment: so I must use `new` to empty the `ArrayList` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The second code is wrong and will throw NullPointerException.

If you want to clear the list :

```
public void callEveryFiveSeconds(){
    myArray.clear();
    //grab array data from server
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
       myArray.add(someData);
    }
}
```

As to which option is better - creating a new `ArrayList` instance or clearing the existing one - the latter should take less memory, since it doesn't have to allocate a new array for the new `ArrayList`. The former would allocate a new `ArrayList` with a new array, and the old `ArrayList` will become eligible for garbage collection. This means that the second option (clearing the list) will save work for the garbage collector, which is also a good thing performance wise.

Clearing the existing list instead of creating a new list each time has another benefit if the number of elements added to the list in each call to `callEveryFiveSeconds` stays similar. The reason for this is that creating a new `ArrayList` without specifying an initial capacity creates a list with a small initial capacity, and if you add many elements to the new list, it will have to be resized multiple times, which also costs time.

Comment: And a further suggestion, he might want to make the `callEveryFiveSeconds()` method `synchronized`.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is called premature optimisation. If you are only calling a method once every 5 seconds then you should just write your code normally, without respect to micro-optimisations. If your program is running on a modern processor then it will be able to perform tens of billions instructions between each method call. Optimising this one method will make no overall difference to your program's performance. Memory wise it seems your array list is only 200 items long. On a 64-bit OS your array list will need less than 2kB to hold all its required memory resources. Again not much in the grand scheme of things when modern computers have gigabytes of memory available.

In actual fact you may be creating more work for your program by using `ArrayList.clear` than by creating a new `ArrayList`. This is because by clearing the `ArrayList` the program has to set each item in the backing array to `null`. However, Java's garbage collector is quite efficient and when it disposes of an unused `ArrayList` it is able to get away with disposing of the backing array without clearing it first.

Given the following micro-benchmarks on my computer, each run ten million times:

```
public static final Object OBJ = new Object();
public static final int LENGTH = 200;

public static ArrayList<Object> clearArrayList(ArrayList<Object> objects) {
    objects.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++) {
        objects.add(OBJ);
    }
    return objects;
}

public static ArrayList<Object> newArrayList() {
    ArrayList<Object> objects = new ArrayList<Object>(LENGTH);
    for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++) {
        objects.add(OBJ);
    }
    return objects;
}
```

The results of which are 870 nanoseconds per call of `newArrayList` and 970 nanoseconds per call of `clearArrayList`. So you can see that using a new `ArrayList` is marginally faster, but not enough to care about. Especially when you're talking about a 100 ns difference every 5 seconds. You'll note that I pre-sized the `ArrayList` for the new run. When the ArrayList wasn't pre-sized the average call took 1690ns. Whilst this is a 50% longer, it's still not enough to care about since you aren't calling this method enough.

### Thread synchronisation benefits when using new

So why use either way? There is one benefit to using a new `ArrayList` and this is that it works better with thread synchronisation. If you repeatedly use the same ArrayList then you must block other threads from accessing the ArrayList whilst you are mutating it. If you use a new `ArrayList` then you can work on creating the new `ArrayList` privately before you make it available for other threads to access.

eg.

```
private ArrayList<Object> objects = new ArrayList<Object>();
private final Object lock = new Object();

public ArrayList<Object> getObjects() {
    synchronized(lock) {
        return objects;
    }
}

public void setObjects(ArrayList<Object> newObjects) {
    synchronized(lock) {
        objects = newObjects;
    }
}

public void callEveryFiveSeconds() {
    // note that this method does not explicitly use synchronisation.
    // Synchronisation is only used when setting objects.
    ArrayList<Object> newObjects = new ArrayList<Object>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        newObjects.add(new Object());
    }
    setObjects(newObjects);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a method named clear() that empties an arraylist:

```
public void callEveryFiveSeconds(){
    myArray.clear();
    //grab array data from server
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
       myArray.add(someData);
    }
}
```

[ArrayList.clear()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#clear--)